# How to convert this one-liner into a generator which returns k elements?

Tags: python, generator, yield

How would you rewrite the following sliding window code using generator?

My issue is that each iteration I want to consume k=100 elements or the number of elements left.

```
n=1005
m=5 
step=2
a=[(i,j) for i in range(0,n-m+1,step) for j in range(0,n-m+1,step) if i<j]
```

I came up with this solution:

Maybe this was a dumb question. Anyways here is a possible, non-optimal solution:

```
def my_gen(n,m,k,step):
    res = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,n-m+1,step):
        for j in range(0,n-m+1,step):                     
            if i<j:
                res.append((i,j))
                count += 1
                if count%k == 0:
                    yield res
                    res = []
    yield res
```

Validating it works:

```
n=104
m=5 # size of the window
step=2
k=8
a=[(i,j) for i in range(0,n-m+1,step) for j in range(0,n-m+1,step) if i<j]

gen=my_gen(n,m,k,step)
b=[]
for g in gen:
    b.extend(g)
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    assert(x==y)
```

Comment: Making your code readable to others is more important that fitting it all on one line.

Comment: Isn't this what yield is for ?

Comment: can you please show us a hint of the ouput you want?